# Android notification information not staying in java class ArrayList

Tags: java, android, service, notifications, android-notifications

I am creating an app that "Catches" all the notifications during a specified time period and then displays them all at one time. However, I am running into an issue with my NotificationListenerService Java class.

I currently am able to "Catch" the nofifications as they come through and stop them from displaying. I am also able to preserve the notification information in ArrayLists (as you can see in the onNotificationPosted method). However, when I try to use one of the ArrayList getters to pull the information into another class, the ArrayList is completly empty. Any thoughts as to why this is and why I can't pull this informaiton in another Java class?

**NotificationListenerService Class**

```
public class NotificationListenerServiceUsage extends NotificationListenerService {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationListenerSer";
    ArrayList<Integer> idMap = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Notification> notificationMap = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind: ");
        return super.onBind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn){
        Integer notificationInt = sbn.getId();
        Notification notificationContent = sbn.getNotification();
        idMap.add(notificationInt);
        notificationMap.add(notificationContent);

        cancelAllNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn){

    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getIdMap() {
        return idMap;
    }

    public ArrayList<Notification> getNotificationMap() {
        return notificationMap;
    }
}
```

**Implementation Class**

```
public class Batch_Notifications extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

     public void getHeldNotifications(View view){
        NotificationListenerServiceUsage noteListenerService = new NotificationListenerServiceUsage();
        ArrayList<Integer> idMap = noteListenerService.getIdMap();
        ArrayList<Notification> notificationMap = noteListenerService.getNotificationMap();
        Log.d(TAG, "getHeldNotifications: " + idMap + notificationMap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not persist data in runtime memory. Your `NotificationListenerService` will not always be running it will destroy and then again Instantiated and now all your properties will reinitialized.

The best way to this type of task is preserve data in a persistent Storage i.e Database. And when you try to send batch notification you get from the database.  You can Use Sqlite database with Android-Room for easy implantation.

Have a look at https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage.